# Tutorial for texture mapping a map onto an Open GL ES sphere?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm not looking for a library or even open source code.  I want to learn how to do this on my own.

Where do I start to find an online tutorial, a book chapter, or other educational material for generating a polygonal model of a 3D sphere suitable for feeding to Open GL ES on an iPhone, and then mapping the polygons to some sort of 2D map data so I can texture map the sphere?  Is there some sort of software tool (blender? maya?) with a tutorial on how to do generate this data?  Where is the best place to start?

Comment: FYI Here's a killer article on building a sphere:

http://marc.blog.atpurpose.com/2009/10/31/creating-sphere-from-a-rectangular-mesh/

awesome huh?!

Bellmont also links to this great old-school article:

http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/sphere_cylinder/

Hope those are relevant in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about these articles?

- [Procedural Spheres in OpenGL ES](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/procedural-spheres-in-opengl-es.html)
- [OpenGL ES From the Ground Up, Part 6: Textures and Texture Mapping](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good stuff about "[iPhone 3D Programming](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/)". Jeff LaMarche also recommends it [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/12/opengl-es-book-recommendation.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Anything that comes out of Jeff's mouth is true.

Answer (score 0):

While not OpenGL ES, I once tried porting across the examples from [this chapter](http://www.opengl.org.ru/docs/pg/0208.html) in the Red Book where they show how to create an icosahedron and subdivide it to produce smooth spheres.  I only got as far as using a simple icosahedron to crudely represent a sphere in the code for my [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) application.  Perhaps you could extend that.

Apple has a Mac sample application, [GLSLShowpiece](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/GLSLShowpiece/Introduction/Intro.html), that textures a sphere in a couple of places, but they use `gluSphere()` to generate the sphere vertices, which is unavailable in OpenGL ES.

To be honest, I'm in the process of replacing the sphere rendering code in Molecules with a 2-D billboarding approach that uses shaders to generate the sphere coloring.  This should allow for far smoother spheres without having to resort to massive amounts of geometry.  See [this paper](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2006/TCM06/Tarini_FinalVersionElec.pdf) for the kind of results you can produce this way.